# Classifying Attribute Table values?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, classification, table

I have an attribute table with a lot of lines.

I want to classify them considering their length:

- SHORT (from 0 to 50)
- MEDIUM (from 50 to 150)
- LONG (from 150 to 180)

How can I do avoiding to modify manually every 391 row?

[image: Table]

This does not work:

```py
Reclass(!Lenght!)

Code Block:
def Reclass(Lenght):
    if Lenght>= 0 and Lenght<= 30
        return "Short"
    elif Lenght> 30 and Lenght<= 90):
        return "Medium"
    elif Lenght> 90 and Lenght<= 180):
        return "Long"
    elif Lenght> 30):
        return "VeryLong"
```

[image]

[image]

Tried with

```
def lenght_cat(length,lenght_cat):
      if lenght> 0 and lenght< 14:
        return (length_cat*short)
      elif lenght> 14 and lenght< 20:
        return (length_cat*long)
      else:
        return None
```

but does not work unfortunately.

Comment: Use Field Calculator. See the example: "Calculate fields using logic with Python" in [Calculate Field examples](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/calculate-field-examples.htm).

Comment: You appear to be using Python syntax with the VB Script parser.

Comment: Have a look at this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/316601/use-a-python-expression-in-field-calculator-to-sum-each-row-across-several-colum/316604#comment515020_316604, it should help you to properly set the field calculator

Comment: There are multiple things wrong: your field calculator appears to be for another dataset, there is no `test` field in your attribute table, you must tick on show codebock and place your code in there, the syntax makes no sense in your code, what are `short` and `long` where do they come from? Your first code example is about reclassifying whilst your second appears to be computing a new value for a non existent field! Finally in your reclass() function you have a closing ) but where is the opening (? That's basic maths you start and end () and your coding is not doing this. Read the help file.